# Linear regression K-fold is not working (ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:) -inside a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to perform a Linear regression followed by k-fold cross validation...for this purpose I'm using the following code:
ps: Ive removed the date column after splited the date into training and test, further I`ve performed a delay of 24 k in order to find the best one(lower rmse) to perform theh final model.

````
>
df= pd.read_csv("sunspots2.csv", sep =";")
T=25

#generating the delay
for K in range(1,T):
  label = 'Sunspot defasado t-' + str(K)
  df[label] = df['Sunspot'].shift(K) # atraso o dado com o valor de K

df_train = df[df.index < '2010'] # train data
df_test = df[df.index >= '2010'] #test

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

lista_reg = []
lista_k = []
lista_rmse=[]
k=0
# for k in list(range(24)):
X = df_train.iloc[25:,k+1]
k= 1+ k
y = df_train['Sunspot'][25:]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y) 
folds = KFold(n_splits=4,shuffle=True)
lista_k.append(k)
scores =(-1)* cross_val_score(regr, X, Y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=folds)
lista_rmse.append(np.sqrt(scores.mean()))```






And then I`m getting the error

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:



How should I proceed? I know that it is a simple error, but I dont know how to fit this to perform the the for loop that I need to the linear regression.    
tks very much!
````

Comment: Which line you get this error? `regr.fit(X, Y)` ?

Comment: Yes, in regr.fit(X,Y)